# Recent movie, girl wakes up and answers A.I. questions while dressing

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw recently at the exhibition "[Into the Unknown](https://www.barbican.org.uk/whats-on/2017/event/into-the-unknown-a-journey-through-science-fiction)" a clip from a sci-fi movie but I can't remember the title.

In the clip, a dark-haired girl wakes up in a futuristic house/station and starts getting dressed. At the same time she, *almost mechanically*, replies to the questions of an A.I. voice (possibly a test).

The movie was probably released around 2010-2015 (but I'm not sure).

---

<sub><sup>It's not Ex Machina or Blade Runner 2049.</sup></sub>

Comment: Could you take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details? Every little bit helps us.

Comment: I recall this. This was an anthology film with two or three different sections. The girl underground in a sterile high-tech environment was contrasted with a guy and a girl living above ground in a ruined world overgrown with weeds. Low budget, probably less than $10M

Comment: She was being tested to check that she hadn't been infected with some disease that had killed the rest of the human population.

Comment: I'm chuckling at those voting to close as ***"Too broad"/"Unclear what you're asking"***. Please don't VTC story-ID questions just because *you* don't know the answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is [*Embers*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3503460/) (2015).

> In a dystopian future, an unidentified virus has caused a neurological
>   disease of global proportions, decimating the majority of the Earth's
>   population. As we observe the lives of a handful of survivors who
>   still remain relatively unharmed by this illness, we understand their
>   struggle to hopelessly attach to their former way of life, where even
>   the simplest of things require great effort to be accomplished. In the
>   end, with varying degrees of memory loss, the need to move on with
>   their lives becomes, inevitably, an arduous task and a fierce battle
>   with the inevitable.

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thanks very much Valorum!

Comment: @GerasimosArtelaris - [What can I say?](http://i.imgur.com/PR2wZfv.gif)

Comment: Why don't you change your name to Holo Doctor? After all, you **are** the database, with two legs and a splendid bedside manner. ;)

Comment: @DuaneDibbley - I was actually tempted to fund this one after seeing the preview trailer on kickstarter. The budget was actually closer to $100K than $10M!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a precise match, but perhaps it's a couple of clips conflated in your memory - Ex Machina?

[Ava gets dressed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=god-9smfGHs)

Comment: Hi Chris, no it is not Ex Machina but thanks anyway! :)